# Angular : How to use HttpClient in a static method service

Tags: angular, typescript

my service contains a static method (which i use for some initilalizing treatment)

In my method i need to fetch some data from a web service

```
    @Injectable()
    export class FeaturesInitializationService {

      static allowedFeaturesModules: any = FeaturesInitializationService.featuresFilter();
      public httpClient : HttpClient ;

      constructor() {
      }

      static featuresFilter() {


// HERE IT's NOT ALLOWED to USE "this.httpClient"
       this.httpClient.get('myUrl').subscribe(    
          ( data ) => {
            console.log(data);
          }
        );
        const testPef = true;
        const featuresList = [];
        if (testPef === true) {
          featuresList.push(MenusModule);
        } else {
          featuresList.push(ChangelogModule);
        }
        return featuresList;
      }
    }
```

as you can see i'm not allowed to use `this.httpClient` as it's a static method

**Suggestions?**

Comment: Why do you need a static method to do your work?

Answer (score 4):

Static methods are not instance methods, simple as that. `this` would only refer to the static class properties, while a non-static `this` refers the the instance of a class-- `httpClient` is not static, so it does not *exist* in a static property.

You could make httpClient static, but then Angular wouldn't be able to inject it into the service instance.

I would question your design here and the reason for needing this method to be static -- services are always created as instances, and I can't really think of a situation where an `httpClient` call would need to be made where a service is not accessible via Angular's DI.

Comment: I can give you an example.  I have an environment-manager class with a method called getApiUrl that will retrieve the URL of this Angular app's API based on which environment.  The URLs of each environment are held in a json file in the assets folder.  The method is static so I can call it inline on my services: 
var apiUrl = environmentManager.getApiUrl() + '/api/User'; As far as I can tell the only way to read a JSON file is with HTTPClient, so I would need it in my static method.

Comment: You would still need to inject it, for example by using a custom provider for the APP_INITIALIZER token and specifying the httpClient as a dependency. Dependency injection and static classes/properties are two different paradigms that don't work with each other. 

Also, I don't see any reason you'd need the client to parse JSON when JSON.parse() is a thing